# How to send a List of images as bytes from multipart post method in flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutterwebviewplugin, flutter-web-browser

I have a List of images as bytes and I would like to send it as a post request in flutter web.

Firstly how do I send the data in file format just like image picker for android/iOS in flutter web

Secondly if I had to send the attachments in the below code what changes would I need to make in multipart in flutter web

If anyone can please help me resolve this.

Let me know if you require any further information from my end

dataInsert.dart

```
File _file = File("zz");
Uint8List webImage = Uint8List(10);


else if (kIsWeb) {
      final imagefile =
          await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, maxWidth: 600);
      
      if (imagefile != null) {
        var f = await imagefile.readAsBytes();

        setState(() {
          _file = File("a");
          webImage = f;
          
          _storedImageWeb.add(webImage);
         
        });
      }
    }
```

Below is the value of webImage on running the above code :

```
[255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 255, 226, 2, 40, 73, 67, 67, 95, 80, 82, 79, 70, 73, 76, 69, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 48, 0, 0, 109, 110, 116, 114, 82, 71, 66, 32, 88, 89, 90, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Multipart.dart

```
Future<void> addUser(
      ProjectDetail stnotification, List<Uint8List> imagecheckb) async {
      
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      "Content-Type": "charset=utf-8",
      "Content-type": "application/json"
    };

    var uri = Uri.parse('http://localhost:4000/check/upload');
    try {
      var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);
      request.headers.addAll(headers);

for (int i = 0; i <= imagecheckb.length - 1; i++) {
        http.MultipartFile multipartFile = await http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
            'attachments', imagecheckb[i].cast());
        request.files.add(multipartFile);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to send a list of files/images from multipart.

```
 await Future.forEach(
    files,
    (file) async => {
      request.files.add(
        http.MultipartFile(
          'files',
          (http.ByteStream(file.openRead())).cast(),
          await file.length(),
          filename: basename(file.path),
        ),
      )
    },
  );
```

Comment: hi thanks for your response can you please explain the above code bcouz I am still getting a lot of error while implementing

Comment: As mentioned in the above code getting the data in this List<Uint8List> imagecheckb,hence it would help if you could explain with respect to above code

Comment: Additionally also getting this error :
The method 'openRead' isn't defined for the type 'Uint8List'.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the list of image by index:

```
Future addProduct(String name, String description, List<File> images) async{
    final request = await http.MultipartRequest(
        'POST',
        Uri.parse('$baseUrl/products/add-product'),
    );

    request.headers.addAll(header);

    request.fields['Name'] = name;
    request.fields['Description'] = description;

    for(int i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
      final f = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('Photos[$i]',images[i].path);
      request.files.add(f);
    }

    final responseStream = await request.send();
    final response = await http.Response.fromStream(responseStream);

    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      print("success")
    } else {
      print('failed')
    }       
 });
```